# Are there ways to store a multidimensional array in a temporary excel or anything else?

Tags: arrays, vba

I am trying to create an Addin which will copy certain attributes of a chart from `First PowerPoint` and read it to an `Temporary Excel`, which then can be used by a second chart in `Second PowerPoint`. Sounds simple enough, but the problem is, the attributes that I am reading happens to be a multidimensional array, which can't be written to an excel. So I have hit a roadblock as to how to tackle this situation.

On searching through internet, I came across something called `localstorage` and most of the answer seems to be surrounding `javascript` which I don't know, so didn't really understand much.

Because this strikes to me like a common problem which others might have also faced at some point in their life, so really hoping to take away some pointers from here.

Comment: What makes you think a multidimensional array can't be written to an Excel sheet? Can you give a sample array you're dealing with?

Comment: Umm... the structure of my array currently is  `Variant(1 to 3, 1 to 8, 1 to 12)`. Unable to imagine how to write this in form of rows and columns

Comment: Definitely doable with multiple sheets, for example. Rows x columns x sheets would give you 3 dimensions.

Comment: You mean a dedicated sheet for each dimension. Hey, that is a nice idea.

Comment: For example, the above array could translate to 8 rows by 12 columns on 3 different sheets. Or 3 rows by 8 columns on 12 different sheets. Or others. Take your pick.

Comment: Thanks Ben, suddenly it is looking doable.

Comment: Note that higher dimension arrays could be representend by a hierarchical index in a 2D table.